# How to get the villain to a prison on another plane?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes

Let's just say I have acquired an Emissary of Barachiel contact, and built a prison on our base plane that can't be broken out of while he gets to talk to the prisoner unhindered (and use the class' features to turn them lawful good over time).

That's all well and good, but sometimes you can't just haul the villain back the moment you beat them. Maybe there's more work to be done.

I am looking for ways to land the villain accurately in the prison without going there, or keeping them on my person safely, easily and indefinitely until I can take them there. I can only use items to do it, as the party shifts and my character isn't a caster nor has room for PrCs.

Comment: Can your PC reliably employ the skill Use Magic Device? Also, when the question says, "I am looking for ways to land the villain accurately in the prison without going there, or keeping them on my person safely, easily and indefinitely until I can take them there," is *them* in the second sentence still the villain or should answers consider the possibility that the PC must, Pokémon-style, have several villains collected at once? Also, what kind of budget is available and what books can be used?

Comment: It's possible I'll deal with multiple villains. Any first-party book is on the table, and the budget is irrelevant.

Comment: Can your PC reliably employ the skill Use Magic Device? To be clear, does an irrelevant budget include creating original magic items based on published guidelines and purchasing an unlimited number of nonepic and epic magic items?

Comment: Mine can, but odds are someone in the party will. As for budget, what I mean by irrelevant is that any answer you can come up with, cheap or expensive, is desired. Obviously, cheap more so.

Comment: Are you allowed to use custom magical items, built using the custom magical item rules?  What manner of creature is this villain?  Do they have inherent planar travel abilities?  Can we assume that given the choice between life as a captive and death they will choose life?  Can we assume that they are initially fully incapacitated?  How large are they, and how much food do they require?

Comment: I am probably allowed custom items. The villain could be anyone and anything, just sentient and evil. Planar travel is dealt with by the prison. They are looking at a month in prison tops, so probably they'll pick life. They are most likely incapacitated, or at least surrendered. No idea on size and food needs, probably not arresting the Tarrasque though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Getting the villain to the prison without going there

A creature that possesses 7 levels in the prestige class master alchemist (*Magic of  Faerûn* 34–5) can brew potions of up to 7th-level spells. This means that a cleric 6/master alchemist 7 can brew a ***potion of greater plane shift*** [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 159) (4,550 gp; 0.1 lbs.). That master alchemist will have to be shown around the prison and instructed to brew the potions based on where the drinker will arrive because the potion's consumer "doesn't get to make any decisions about the [potion's] effect [because] the caster who brewed the potion has already done so" (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 229). However, once such an NPC is employed to make the potions for you, as long as the potions remain clearly labeled with cell numbers and everything, just dump a potion down an unconscious foe's throat and—*poof!*—the foe arrives in the appropriate cell of your off-plane prison.

## Long-term restraint of defeated prisoners

The 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell ***stupor*** [ench] (*Book of Vile Darkness* 106) says

> The caster places one creature already helpless in a clouded, confused state that does not allow the subject to think clearly or take actions. The effect is similar to being  drugged. The subject can be moved and even forced to walk on her own if dragged along,  but she is unaware of what is going on around her.

The spell lacks the descriptor evil but possesses the descriptor mind-affecting, limiting somewhat its efficacy. However, its duration is 1 hour/level. Buy a ***wand of extended stupor*** [ench] (*Book of Vile Darkness* 106) (1st-level spell modified to an effective 2nd-level spell at caster level 12) (360 gp/charge) and be sure to use another charge right before the duration of the last one's about to expire. (A custom magic item that leaves a creature continually affected by a *stupor* effect may have a price less than a *wand*, but ask the DM.)

Thus, after affecting a defeated creature with the spell *stupor*, you can equip them with appropriate [survival](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-sustenance) [gear](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#necklace-of-adaptation) and toss them in the [oversized extradimensional](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#portable-hole) [storage space](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#bag-of-holding) of your choosing. Just be sure to check on prisoners daily to renew the *stupor* effect.

Answer (score 1):

## Portable holes are your friends.

Quick and dirty answer: a scroll of stone to flesh (lvl 6 wizard), a scroll of flesh to stone (same), and a portable hole (20,000 gp).  There are a few issues with this one. There's a fortitude save 15 at the end, and if the target fails that one, they die.  Given that having them dead is apparently not an acceptable alternative (and, by extension, that they'd resist attempts to raise dead) they might just choose to fail that save.  Also, you need someone to successfully cast 6th-level wizard spells from scrolls, and you may need to do it more than once if you can't get them to fail their initial saves voluntarily.

No consumables answer: a portable hole (20,000 gp), a ring of sustenance (2500 gp), and a necklace of adaptation (9000 gp).  This assumes that he's not willing to suffocate or die of dehydration, that he's either not willing or not able to deliberately kill himself, and that he's not able to escape an extradimensional space by himself, once otherwise stripped of gear.  If the target is capable of dimensional travel, but not capable of generating a +10 strmod, then Dimensional Shackles (28000 gp) will handle that issue.

## Or you could lob him through a Gate

Gate is a 9th-level Cleric/Wizard/etc spell, and will let you open up a gate to throw him through (into the prison cell).  It's not entirely impossible that you might be able to field someone who could cast that off a scroll. It might get pretty expensive, though, if you start having to deal with a failure chance.  Each scroll will run you 3825 gp.